# Mapquest returning 2 records, one of them is bogus. What can I do?

Tags: mapquest

I am searching for Easton, PA using the api. The URL sent to mapquest looks like this:

```
http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=your_key_here&location=Easton,PA&outFormat=xml&maxresults=1
```

the results are these (even though I have maxresults=1)

```
<lat>40.689353</lat> <lng>-75.216698</lng>
```

and

```
<lat>41.127201</lat> <lng>-79.5411</lng>
```

I cannot find an Easton in Clarion County. Any idea why is it working like this and how can I avoid these types of cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from MapQuest. Looks like the parameter names are case sensitive.

not good:

```
http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=your_key_here&location=Easton,PA&outFormat=xml&maxresults=1
```

good:

```
http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=your_key_here&location=Easton,PA&outFormat=xml&maxResults=1
```